# Multi-site, single code-base user registration using ASPNet.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I have multiple websites running off one code base (asp.net standard MVC). I'm using the built in ASPNet.Identity methods for users to register/log in (using ApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationUserManager).

Currently, all websites are using a single database to store user information. This is causing a couple of issues:

1. When user A registers on website A, they are now able to log into website B with the same details. As far as they are aware, they did not register on website B. Not good!
2. If I constrain user A to only access website A, if that user then tried to register on website B, they get the 'email address already in use' error. Also not good!

I've tried separating the databases, one per site, to get around this issue but I don't know how to dynamically change the DBContext assigned to the ApplicationSignInManager and ApplicationUserManager in my controller.

For example, when a user comes to website A, I grab the connection string for website A and perform login/register actions. I need the domain name to work out which connection string to load, which I can't access until after startup.cs code has run, configuring my manager instances.

I figure other people must have done this. Ideally I need to dynamically change the DBContext AFTER Startup.cs has run. Failing that, I need a nice approach to storing multiple identical email addresses in the same DB

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a flag somewhere which website the current context is for, i'd say easiest to achieve that is to do two things:

- extend the IdentityUser with a Website property, something simple either just an int WebsiteId or a String.
- extend the AccountController to use that property wherever needed, I think you'd need  to modify "Register" and all "Login" functions to verify the website the account is for.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The issue here is that .net enforces unique email address/user name. If user A registers on website A, they will not be able to register on website B as the email already exists in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. It's not the most elegant but it solves the issue until I can figure out how to dynamically change the DB Context used during login/register

In IdentityConfig.cs I switched 'RequireUniqueEmail' to false:

```
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
{
    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
    RequireUniqueEmail = false
};
```

Then when a user registers, I take the email address, make it unique to the website they registered on, and store it in the UserName field (I don't use the UserName for anything). When they log in, I make the same alteration to the entered email address before attempting login.

If this user registers on a different website, the username will be different even though the email is identical. Not perfect, but it works.

E.g.

```
string uniqueCode = "Website_Specific_String";
var user = new ApplicationUser { uniqueCode + model.Email, Email = model.Email};
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

and the login

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(uniqueCode  + model.Email);
```

Still open to better ideas. Thanks